# Get number of result sets from a SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqldatareader

I have an SQL Server stored procedure that returns multiple results. The body of the stored procedure might look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA;
SELECT * FROM tableB;
SELECT * FROM tableC;
```

In that case, the stored procedure returns 3 result sets. Other stored procedures might return, e.g., 1, 0, or any number of result sets. Each result set might contain 0 or more rows in it. When loading these, I will need to call [`IDataReader.NextResult()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.nextresult(v=vs.110).aspx) to navigate between result sets.

How can I reliably get the count of result sets (not row counts) in C#?

Comment: What do you mean with count, the count of result sets or the count of each row count?

Comment: Prop the count of the result from all those select, like he said.

Comment: i mean count of result sets (above tree). each set can contains some rows

Comment: I don't think there's any way to count the number of result sets - you just have to **enumerate** them (using `reader.GetNextResult()`) and handle them. You cannot determine ahead of time how many result sets you'll be handling, though

Comment: Just to expand on marc_s comment.  I would presume that moving the reader past a result would not allow me to go back - so I can't know ahead of time reliably in a dynamic way.  Even if it worked today I could expect an implementation change tomorrow that would break my assumption or hack that made it work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`DataReader.NextResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.data.datareader.nextresult.aspx) to advance the reader to the next result set.:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString))
{
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TableA; SELECT * FROM TableB; SELECT * FROM TableC;", con))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (IDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                int firstIntCol = rdr.GetInt32(0); // assuming the first column is of type Int32
                // other fields ...
            }
            if (rdr.NextResult())
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    int firstIntCol = rdr.GetInt32(0); // assuming the first column is of type Int32
                    // other fields ...
                }
                if (rdr.NextResult())
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        int firstIntCol = rdr.GetInt32(0); // assuming the first column is of type Int32
                        // other fields ...
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if (rdr.NextResult()) count++; do you have any idea? method NextResult() move position the sqldatareader

Comment: @Mikhail: Explain your question. Do you need the count of each table's rows or do you need the count of result sets or do you need the rows of each result set(as shown above)? If you just need the count of result sets: `int count = 0; while(rdr.NextResult())count++;` should work.

Comment: Ok, if i use this method, how i can return position of sqldatareader before the first record after counting?

Comment: @isxaker The point is that you can’t. You can read all of the data into a collection such as a [`List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) (you’ll need something more complex if handling multiple result sets) and then you can both [count data points](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3.aspx) and [use the data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ebtbkkc.aspx).

Answer (score 11):

There seems to be no property or method that directly calculates the result count in [`IDataReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.aspx). This interface rather intends to be consumed in an incremental/streaming fashion. So, to count the number of result sets returned, increment a counter every time you call [`IDataReader.NextResult()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.nextresult%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and it returns `true` while consuming the data.

However, there is a catch. The 
The documentation for [`IDataReader.NextResult()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.nextresult%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) states:

> By default, the data reader is positioned on the first result.

Consider the following scenarios:

- The command returned 0 result sets. Your first call to `IDataReader.NextResult()` returns `false`.
- The command returned 1 result set. Your first call to `IDataReader.NextResult()` returns `false`.
- The command returned 2 result sets. Your second call to `IDataReader.NextResult()` returns `false`.

You can see that we have enough information to count the number of result sets as long as there is at least one result set. That would be the number of times that `IDataReader.NextResult()` returned `true` plus one.

To detect whether or not there are 0 result sets, we use another property from the reader: [`IDataRecord.FieldCount`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatarecord.fieldcount(v=vs.110).aspx). The documentation for this property states:

> When not positioned in a valid recordset, 0; otherwise, the number of columns in the current record. The default is -1.

Thus, we can read that field when first opening the reader to determine if we are in a valid result set or not. If the command generates no result sets, the value of `IDataRecord.FieldCount` on the reader will initially be less than 1. If the command generates at least one result set, the value will initially be positive. This assumes that it is impossible for a result set to have 0 columns (which I think you can assume with SQL, not sure).

So, I would use something like the following to count the number of result sets. If you also need to save the data, that logic must be inserted into this:

```
using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    var resultCount = 0;
    do
    {
        if (reader.FieldCount > 0)
            resultCount++;

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // Insert logic to actually consume data here…
            // HandleRecordByResultIndex(resultCount - 1, (IDataRecord)reader);
        }
    } while (reader.NextResult());
}
```

I’ve tested this with `System.Data.SqlClient` and the commands `PRINT 'hi'` (0 result sets), `SELECT 1 x WHERE 1=0` (1 result set), and `SELECT 1 x WHERE 1=0; SELECT 1 x WHERE 1=0` (2 result sets).

Comment: Depending on the scenario, I have also used `SqlDataReader.HasRows` instead of `FieldCount` (I probably use `HasRows` more often than `FieldCount`). But yes, a `do {...} while()` is a far better (and cleaner) approach than the convoluted, and less flexible, approach shown in the accepted answer. (+1). And correct, a result set must have at least one column.

Comment: @srutzky The code I've written will probably never be anything other than `System.Data.SqlClient` and I have no abstraction over raw T-SQL, but I still find it fun to try to restrict myself to the available interfaces (except to take advantage of the TPL compatible `Async()` variants for which I use `DbCommand`). `FieldCount` does feel hacky, but at least I can get “pure” interfacy code ;-)

Comment: This is a perfect answer to my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to be aware of, in addition to the manual `SqlDataReader` method, in the accepted answer, is to use a `SqlDataAdapter` and `DataSet`s and `DataTable`s.

When using those classes, the entire result set is retrieved from the server in one go, and you can iterate them at your leisure. Also, several other .net classes are aware of DataSets and DataTables and can be hooked up to them directly, for read-only or read-write data access, if you also set the `DeleteCommand`, `InsertCommand`, and `UpdateCommand` properties. What you get "for free," with that, is the ability to alter the data in the `DataSet`, and then simply call `Update()` to push your local changes to the database. You also gain the `RowUpdated` event handler, which you can use to make that happen automatically.

`DataSet`s and `DataTable`s retain the metadata from the database schema, as well, so you can still access columns by name or index, as you please.

Overall, they're a nice feature, though certainly heavier weight than a `SqlDataReader` is.

Documentation for `SqlDataAdapter` is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter